# What rep is required to edit / propose an edit on a question?

Tags: support

What is the required amount of reputation required to edit a question?  I'm not referring to the 2,000 rep style of edit, I'm referring to the propose an edit feature where it has to be peer reviewed and gives you 2 rep.

I looked here on meta, which got me to [this page](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), but I don't see it listed anywhere.

Does that mean you can do it as soon as you register?

Comment: Even anonymous unregistered individuals can do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Editing is a basic feature that anyone can do. I just rejected an edit from a 1 rep person today.